# `Type not matched' error in jquery.ajax callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I have following html layout:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="addnew_sub">
<input type="hidden" name="tgtid" value="item">
<input type="hidden" name="crit" value="">

<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Product Type: </td>
<td>
    <select name="type">
        <option>Tablet</option>
        <option>Capsule</option>
        <option>Syrup</option>
        <option>Suspension</option>
        <option>Cream</option>
        <option>Oinment</option>
        <option>Drop</option>
        <option>Sachet</option>
        <option>Suppository</option>
        <option>Injection</option>
        <option>Pfs</option>
        <option>Vial</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Product Unit: </td>
<td>
    <select name="unit">
        <option>Tabs</option>
        <option>Caps</option>
        <option>Phials</option>
        <option>Sachets</option>
        <option>Vials</option>
        <option>Tubes</option>
        <option>Packs</option>
        <option>Cycles</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Generic Name: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="generic" size="70" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Strength: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="strength" size="5" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Strength Unit: </td>
<td>
    <select name="sunit">
        <option>nil</option>
        <option>mg</option>
        <option>gm</option>
        <option>ml</option>
        <option>pc</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" class="addnew_sub" value="submit" name="submit"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

And following ajax code:

```
   var myClass = this.classList;
   if(myClass[1]=='addnew_sub'){
   var act = myClass[1];
   var tgtid = null;
   var formid = $(this).closest('form').attr('id');
    var frm = "#"+formid ;
    var data = $(frm).serializeArray();
    data.push({name:'action',value:act});
    data.push({name:'tgtid',value:tgtid});
    getdirData(data);
  }

function getdirData(data){
  $.ajax({
      url,
      data: data,
      type:"POST",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(cbdata){
          $("#result").html(cbdata).show();
               }
  });
}
```

and the processing php page code:

```
  extract($_POST);
  if($action=='addnew_sub'){
    echo 'Data received successfully<br />';
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$val){
      echo 'Key: '.$key.' Value: '.$val.'<br />';
    }
  }
```

and the output is:

```
Type not matched
Data received successfully
Key: tgtid Value: item
Key: crit Value: 
Key: type Value: Tablet
Key: unit Value: Tabs
Key: generic Value: This is my entered text
Key: strength Value: 2000
Key: sunit Value: mg
Key: action Value: addnew_sub
```

I am unable to find why 'Type not matched' is coming at the beginning of the above output. If I exclude form data by `serializeArray()`, the output is fine.

Do you have any idea, from which 'Type not mached'?

Comment: `$action` is not available i guess. it is inside of posted data.

Comment: Could not understand. $action is available through `data.push({name:'action',value:act});` and `var act = myClass[1];` which is `addnew_sub`

Comment: `$action` at php you have not shown how you are extracting the value from the posted data.

Comment: Oh, I see...I forgot to mention...I have updated my question. Now please review my question.